# get value from input type hidden and access in items <c:foreach>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, foreach, hidden-field

I have  input type hidden variable in jsp

```
  <input type="hidden" name="propMap" id="propMap" value="">
```

The value of this input type parameter I will set from javascript Ajax success `$("#propMap").val(data);`

in the same jsp I have the code

```
<c:forEach items="" var="i">
  <tr>
     <td>${i.key}</td>
     <td>${i.value}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The thing is I need to access the hidden **propMap** value in **c:foreach items** in jsp

Will I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this format for looping the data:

```
<c:forEach var="dataList" items="${dataFrom}">
  <span>${dataList.key}</span>
  <span>${dataList.value}</span>
</c:forEach>
```